# How do buoyancy and pseudo forces combine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, water, buoyancy

[image]

**About the diagram:**

A tennis ball is attached to a string which is attached to the jar.

The string is mass less.

The density of the ball is less than that of water.

**The F.B.D of the tennis ball:**

[image]

Thus the ball is balanced by all this forces...

**Experiment:**

If we move the jar towards right then due to pseudo force,the ball will moves towards left,which is a obvious scene to observe,right.

**My question:**

If the jar moves towards right,as the ball has less density than the water, then the water must make the ball move towards right with it along the jar. I mean the buoyant forces acting from the left side will be now more as compared to right side of the jar, because we are pushing the jar from left to right,also as the density if the water is more thus,the force is also more,as compared to the ball's force.

I know I am thinking wrong somewhere, because it is at last the pseudo force making the ball moves towards the left, by can anyone explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: Also, your question needs to be much clearer. Let me know if this is what you are asking: when you push the entire apparatus to the right, does the ball move to the left or the right?

Comment: yes your 1st comment was right,let me correct it...

Comment: Furthermore, why do you think the ball will move to the left in this experiment? Your argument ("due to pseudo force") isn't very clear to me. Also, I assume you are *accelerating* the system, not just moving it at a constant velocity?

Comment: @Philip,sir,for your second comment.Actually I know that the ball will move towards left,but I have a question which I have described above,if you are having any problem please let me know..

Comment: Please make the title of the question more descriptive of the actual question content

Comment: Yes,sir it is an accelerated motion,as I am first making it move from rest.But I am not making it move very far,just a bit away from its mean position and then stopping it.And is it is obvious that due to the pseudo force it will move towards left,but then comes my question

Comment: @BioPhysicist,of course sir,I thought about it a bit,but then I nothing came to my mind,as this question,is of my own.I just wanted discuss it with the experts here,so that I will get a clear vision

Answer (score 1):

We can understand gravity as equivalent to the ground having an uniform acceleration of $g$ upwards in a region of space without gravity. The effect of an additional horizontal acceleration is to change that (pseudo)acceleration vector.

All passes as, inside the jar, the force of gravity was tilted: the level of the water has an inclination (left side higher that right side for an external observer).

For that new gravity configuration, the ball must also be inclined to the right, keeping normal to the water surface.

Comment: Sir,can please elaborate a bit please,I am not able to understand.By the way the water is completely full ,then wher does the inclination come in the first place. Also,I have a question,i.e if we have a denser ball as compared to water and hang it by the top part of the jar,and then try the experiment agian then,we will find the ball moving in opposite direction to that of the jar.Why?

Comment: The fact that the jar is full doesn't change the argument. For a denser ball it goes to the left, because the string have to be aligned with the "new gravity" direction. That means: from lower left to upper right.

Comment: Honestly speaking sir,I have been following your answers and I found them quite tricky,like you write the most meaningful things in such a short sentence,thats it's like decoding your answer,anyway thank you for giving me your valuable time.....

Comment: My answer is based in the principle of equivalence between gravity and acceleration. Once we accept that principle, the problem is easy. It is as gravity were already a pseudo-force. Any additional acceleration can be regarded as a modification of the $g$ direction and modulus.

Comment: Hmm,let me do some research upon that,thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration of the jar to the right does indeed create a pseudo force to the left when your reference frame accelerates with the jar.

This pseudo force can be treated exactly like you normally treat gravity. The magnitude will exactly match the magnitude of the acceleration.

The force on the ball directly to the left would therefore be equal to
$$F = m\,a$$
The buoyant force to the right would be:
$$F = \rho_{water} \, V \, a $$
Since the water is more dense than the ball, the buoyant force would be greater and the ball would accelerate to the right.

Comment: Clear cut explanation,thank you sir.....

Answer (score 0):

You should just du the experiment! accelerating your jar to the right , the ball will go to the right too, an yes it ist the inertia of water and ball wich act together. You may find it earthier to take a Helium filled ballon in your car and see what it does when you accelerate or brake or drive in a curve.

Comment: Sir my question is that when we push the jar from left the forces inside the jar gets unbalanced and thus we should have the ball moved towards the right along with the jar,but the ball moves towards the left,due to pseudo force,my question is where I am I  going wrong with my experiment

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you call pseudo forces, the ball has less inertia, than the water, so the water stays left pressure left is greater than pressure right  and the ball moves right relativ to the water.